# CKEDITOR ImageToolBox floating

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

For my ASP.NET MVC 5 web application, I use CKEDITOR in a modal. Everything works except the toolbox for selecting the position of the image.

In reality, by applying an opacity to the modal, I see the image toolbox but it is as if it is displayed under the modal.

How can I apply a custom style to have a higher zindex?

I tried to apply a style but I can't